# Correct way define and convert the Moose attribute type

Tags: perl, moose

Have:

```
package MyPath;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

has 'path' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Path::Class::Dir',
    required => 1,
);
1;
```

But want create this object with two ways, like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyPath;
use Path::Class;
my $o1 = MyPath->new(path => dir('/string/path')); #as Path::Class::Dir
my $o2 = MyPath->new(path => '/string/path'); #as string (dies - on attr type)
```

And when call it with a 'Str' - want convert it internally in the MyPath package to Class::Path::Dir, so, both: `$o1->path` and `$o2->path` should return blessed `Path::Class::Dir`

When I tried extend the definition to the next:

```
has 'path' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Path::Class::Dir|Str',    #allowing both attr types
    required => 1,
);
```

It doesn't works and still need "somewhat" convert the `Str` to `Path::Class::Dir` automatically-internally in the `package MyPath`...

Could someone give me some hints?

EDIT: Based on Oesor's hint I found than i need someting like:

```
coerce Directory,
    from Str,       via { Path::Class::Dir->new($_) };

has 'path' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Directory',
    required => 1,
);
```

But still havent idea how to correctly use it...

Some more hints please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for type coersion.

```
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
use Path::Class::Dir;

subtype 'Path::Class::Dir',
   as 'Object',
   where { $_->isa('Path::Class::Dir') };

coerce 'Path::Class::Dir',
    from 'Str',
        via { Path::Class::Dir->new($_) };

has 'path' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Path::Class::Dir',
    required => 1,
    coerce   => 1,
);
```

Comment: Your `subtype 'Path::Class::Dir' ...` declaration could be written more naturally as `class_type 'Path::Class::Dir';`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -- look for how to coerce the value:

[https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTypes)

Comment: Can you please add some more hints? I edited my question... (Probably needed 1-2 more lines - can you please give me an answer? :)